# Running Scheduled Job only on single instance in vertx Application

Tags: java, deployment, vert.x

In my Vertx(Java) Application there are few Scheduled job(Written in java). These job either read/update redis or DB. When I deploy the application on multiple instance, All instances run their own copy of job. I need a solution where only one instance runs the Scheduled job.

Comment: Pretty hard to suggest something without code of your schedulers.

Comment: There is no specific code for scheduler we just trigger it based on given schedule. We just want the mechanism if the cron is already started on one of the instances , then we should not run it again.

Comment: And how do you run your instances? Are you using clustered mode?

Comment: you can use a semaphore in a table, so each instance is going to query that table to know if other instance is running the process

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are deploying verticle in your project as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
  vertx.deployVerticle(YourVerticle.class.getName(), new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(10));
}
```

And you can schedule periodic tasks in this way, which will only trigger task once at a give time point.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
  vertx.setPeriodic(10 * 1000, 10 * 60 * 1000,
      (timerId) -> {
          // the actual task code
      });
  vertx.deployVerticle(YourVerticle.class.getName(), new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(10));
}
```